# Properly scheduling nested functions with asyncio

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I'm having trouble scheduling work with asyncio. I have a code like this:

```py
import asyncio


async def stream():
    char_string = "Hi. Hello. Hello."

    for char in char_string:
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)  # something time consuming happening here
        print("got char:", char)
        yield char


async def sentences_generator():
    sentence = ""
    async for char in stream():
        sentence += char
        if char in [".", "!", "?"]:
            print("got sentence: ", sentence)
            yield sentence
            sentence = ""


async def process_sentence(sentence: str):
    print("waiting for processing sentence: ", sentence)
    await asyncio.sleep(len(sentence)*0.1)
    print("sentence processed!")


async def main():
    i=0
    async for sentence in sentences_generator():
        print("processing sentence: ", i)
        await process_sentence(sentence)
        i += 1

asyncio.run(main())
```

This is my output:

```
got char: H
got char: i
got char: .
got sentence:  Hi.
processing sentence:  0
waiting for processing sentence:  Hi.
sentence processed!
got char:  
got char: H
got char: e
got char: y
got char: .
got sentence:   Hey.
processing sentence:  1
waiting for processing sentence:   Hey.
sentence processed!
got char:  
got char: H
got char: e
got char: l
got char: l
got char: o
got char: .
got sentence:   Hello.
processing sentence:  2
waiting for processing sentence:   Hello.
sentence processed!
```

This is not optimal. While the `process_sentence` is awaiting `asyncio.sleep()` (representing some other time consuming process), it should be already taking next chars from the stream. So, I would expect an output like this:

```
got char: H
got char: i
got char: .
got sentence:  Hi.
processing sentence:  0
waiting for processing sentence:  Hi.
got char:  # (space char)
got char: H
sentence processed!
got char: e
got char: y
got char: .
got sentence:   Hey.
processing sentence:  1
waiting for processing sentence:   Hey.
got char  # (space char)
got char H
got char: e
sentence processed!
got char: l
got char: l
got char: o
got char: .
got sentence:   Hello.
processing sentence:  2
waiting for processing sentence:   Hello.
sentence processed!
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Did you check the answers?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your desired output by creating asynchronous tasks which can run independently. In your code, you're not creating tasks correctly.

**Note**: your `char_string` should not be `"Hi. Hello. Thank you."`, instead, it should be `"Hi. Hey. Hello."`.

The following piece of code will give your required output, which is to process the next chars from the stream while `process_sentence()` is on wait: [Here's the link to your running code](https://onecompiler.com/python/3zydzfjad)

```
import asyncio

async def stream(queue):
    char_string = "Hi. Hey. Hello."

    for char in char_string:
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)  # something time-consuming happening here
        print("got char:", char)
        await queue.put(char)

    # Signal the end of the stream
    await queue.put(None)


async def sentences_generator(queue):
    sentence = ""
    while True:
        char = await queue.get()
        if char is None:
            break
        sentence += char
        if char in [".", "!", "?"]:
            print("got sentence:", sentence)
            yield sentence
            sentence = ""


async def process_sentence(sentence: str):
    print("waiting for processing sentence:", sentence)
    await asyncio.sleep(len(sentence) * 0.1)
    print("sentence processed!")


async def main():
    q = asyncio.Queue()

    # Run the stream coroutine concurrently
    stream_task = asyncio.create_task(stream(q))

    counter = 0
    async for sentence in sentences_generator(q):
        print("processing sentence:", counter)
        counter += 1
        sentence_task = asyncio.create_task(process_sentence(sentence))
        await sentence_task

    # Wait for the stream to finish
    await stream_task


# Run the coroutine
asyncio.run(main())
```

After running this will generate the following output:

```
got char: H
got char: i
got char: .
got sentence: Hi.
processing sentence: 0
waiting for processing sentence: Hi.
got char:  # <empty char>
got char: H
sentence processed!
got char: e
got char: y
got char: .
got sentence:  Hey.
processing sentence: 1
waiting for processing sentence:  Hey.
got char:  # <empty char>
got char: H
got char: e
got char: l
sentence processed!
got char: l
got char: o
got char: .
got sentence:  Hello.
processing sentence: 2
waiting for processing sentence:  Hello.
sentence processed!
```

Answer (score 0):

> This is not optimal. While the process_sentence is awaiting
> asyncio.sleep(), it
> should be already taking next chars from the stream.

In this setup it's not possible. `await` basically blocks the running task/coroutine.

In code below:

```py
async def main():
    i = 0
    async for sentence in sentences_generator():
        print("processing sentence: ", i)
        await process_sentence(sentence)
        i += 1
```

when would you see the `"got char:"` string? when the first line executes (`async for`) but here `await process_sentence(sentence)` blocks the `main()`.

What you can do instead is using a Queue. The task that produces the characters(producer), can push them into the Queue and the task that uses the character (consumer), can get the item from the Queue. This way the producer will populate the Queue even if the consumer still waiting for some time before getting the characters. They would work independently.

```py
import asyncio

async def stream():
    char_string = "Hi. Hello. Thank you."
    for char in char_string:
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
        print("got char:", char)
        yield char

async def sentences_generator(q: asyncio.Queue[str], flag: asyncio.Event):
    sentence = ""
    async for char in stream():
        sentence += char
        if char in [".", "!", "?"]:
            print("got sentence: ", sentence)
            await q.put(sentence)
            sentence = ""
    flag.set()

async def process_sentence(q: asyncio.Queue[str], flag: asyncio.Event):
    global i
    while not (q.empty() and flag.is_set()):
        item = await q.get()
        print("processing sentence: ", i)
        print("waiting for processing sentence: ", item)
        await asyncio.sleep(len(item) * 0.1)
        print("sentence processed!")
        i += 1

async def main():
    global i
    i = 1
    event = asyncio.Event()
    queue = asyncio.Queue[str]()
    producer = sentences_generator(queue, event)
    consumer = process_sentence(queue, event)
    await asyncio.gather(producer, consumer)

asyncio.run(main())
```